# How to find distinct lines from a set of lines

Tags: linear-algebra

Source : https://www.codechef.com/DEC15/problems/PLANEDIV

In short, given a set of lines find out the size of the largest perfect subset of this set, Let's call a set of lines to be perfect if there does not exist a point that belongs to two or more distinct lines of the set.

In the example

$x=0$

$x+2y+3 = 0$

$3x+4y+5 = 0$

$30x+40y = 0$

$30x+40y+50=0$

for the above the answer is $2$ and that set contains $3*x + 4*y + 5 = 0$ and $30*x + 40*y + 0 = 0$

why $30x+40y+50=0$ is not part of the set even thought all three are parallel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$30x+40y+50=10(3x+4y+5)$. So it represents the same line . Hence its excluded from the set.

Comment: Does this has anything to do with being distinct?, when I googled for distinct lines I couldn't get any good explanation.

Comment: Its the same line when divided by 10 so itll be counting the same line twice if any variables satisfy 1st eqn then necessarily it hs to satisfy the 30x+40y+50 so it does not show any uniqueness.